# Ionic&Angular How to send a hardcoded push notification?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am trying to send a push notification to my phone when I get connected or disconnected from the wifi hardcoded. I am not looking to use firebase it just has to say you have been disconnected or connected.

I have looked online but can only find examples which use firebase

How can I do this simply hardcoded?

**app.component.ts**

````
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, Events } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
import { NetworkProvider } from '../app/network-provider';

import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions} from '@ionic-native/push/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public events: Events,
    public network: Network,
    public networkProvider: NetworkProvider,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private push: Push
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      this.push.hasPermission()
          .then((res: any) => {
        
            if (res.isEnabled) {
              console.log('We have permission to send push notifications');
            } else {
              console.log('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
            }
        
          }); 

      this.networkProvider.initializeNetworkEvents();

      this.push.createChannel({
        id: "notification",
        description: "My first test channel",
        importance: 3
       }).then(() => console.log('Channel created'));

      const options: PushOptions = {
        android: {},
        ios: {
            alert: 'true',
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {},
        browser: {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        }
     }

      const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
                // Offline event
                this.events.subscribe('network:offline', () => {
              alert('network:offline ==> '+this.network.type);   
              pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification)); 
              console.log("Geen WIFI");  
                });

                // Online event
                this.events.subscribe('network:online', () => {
              alert('network:online ==> '+this.network.type); 
              pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification)); 
              console.log("Wel WIFI");    
          }); 
                   
    });
  }
}

```
````

Comment: What do you mean by hard coded and what is exactly the thing that is not working (network part or notification part)?

Comment: I found it i mean that i dont want to use firebase but i was able to solve this with local notifications

Comment: Yeah that what i needed to say,why are you using the push...